# ADF remove line break from column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do a copy activity in Azure Data Factory, here is how the data looks

Source: Dynamics 365 entity

```
A(GUID) | B(boolean) | C(string)
04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4| False | "some text \n\n next line \n new line"
```

Sink: Azure Blob delimited text file

```
A(string) | B(string) | C(string)
04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4| False | "some text

next line
new line"
```

I have set the sink mapping in copy activity to string. But the result does not add quotes to the values of A and B field.

Expected result:

```
"04741b89-3d51-ea11-a811-000d3af427b4"| "False" | "some text next line new line"
```

How do i remove the line breaks?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by adding a dataflow activity before copy activity
In dataflow activity i added a derived column transform
[image]

In derived column settings mention the column to transform. I used a string replace expression to replace \n with empty string.

[image]